# Reference types: Passing one object to multiple classes?

Tags: c#, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to wrap my head around how reference types behave. It's my understanding that classes are reference types. Let's say I have a class with a constructor that takes a `MyObject` type as a parameter. If I pass the same `MyObject` instance to both classes and then modify it in one class, will I be able to see the changes in both classes? For example:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass(myObject);
MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass(myObject);

myClass1.myObject.Name = "Joe";
```

If I refer to `myClass2.myObject.Name` will that reflect the changes that were done to `myClass1.myObject.Name`?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What does the MyClass constructor do? And how is MyClass.myObject defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only creating one instance of `myObject` so what happens is that both classes will point to the same thing:

[image]

Regardless of how you access it, you are always modifying the same object:

```
myClass1.myObject.Name = "Example"
myClass2.myObject.Name == "Example" //true
```

Comment: `You are only creating one instance of myObject`  No, actually, he's not.  The last line is changing one of the variables to reference a new object, rather than mutating it.

Answer (score 4):

No, since you've only overwritten the reference of `myClass1.myObject` and not it's contents.

Edit: Yes, when you mutate `myClass1` e.g. change the `Name` Property, but not when you overwrite the reference of `myClass1`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you use it this way. And if MyObject is `class`, not `struct`:

```
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass(myObject);
    MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass(myObject);

    myClass1.myObject.Name = "Joe";
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of reference types as holding "object IDs", and think of the expression "someReference.DoSomething()" as meaning "Find the object whose ID is *_*_, and perform the DoSomething() method upon it"; a statement like "reference1 = reference2" says to copy the object ID stored in reference2 into reference1.  Note that the first statement does not modify `someReference`; if it held "object id #8675309" before it executed, it will continue to do so after.  Note further that the second statement does not modify the object referred to by `reference1`, nor does it modify any object which used to be referred to by `reference2`.

There are very few things one can actually do with object references in .NET languages; anything that involves a member of a reference type [e.g. `myCar.Color = Blue;`] won't act upon the storage location of the reference type, but will instead act upon the object whose ID is stored in that location.

It's important to note that value types work differently from reference types.  A storage location of a primitive value type (e.g. `Int32`) actually holds a value; a storage location of a structure type (e.g. `Drawing.Point`) holds all the instance fields (whether public, internal, or private) of that type.  Copying one value-type storage location to another will overwrite all the fields of the destination with values taken from the first, and accessing the members of a value type will actually access the fields stored within it.

Some people think it's evil that one is allowed to write code like:

```
Point myPoints[1000];
myPoints[0] = startPosition;
myPoints[1] = startPosition;
myPoints[0].X += 4;
```

which will modify some of the data in `myPoint[0]` while leaving all other copies of `startPosition` untouched.  Such behavior is very different from the behavior of class objects, and one definitely needs to be aware of it, but it can also be very useful in its own right.

Answer (score -1):

Your classes contains 2 references on single object

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass(myObject);
MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass(myObject);
```

if you will change some properties into myObject, then myClass2 and myClass1 also getting this changes.

```
myObject.myProperty=1;

myClass2.myObject.myProperty==1
myClass1.myObject.myProperty==1
```

You can change reference for one class

```
myClass2.myObject=GetNewMyObject();
myClass2.myObject.myProperty==2;
```

so you will see

```
myClass2.myObject.myProperty==2
myClass1.myObject.myProperty==1
```

Comment: But he's *not* mutating the `MyObject` instance, so he *won't* see that behavior.